# How to resolve syntax error on print file=file in linux

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python.  I am receiving an syntax error on file=file_out.
below is the error, then the code is after that.  I have been copying and pasting the code from the internet.  The ^ is under the = between file=file_out on the print line.

Error:

> File "./xxx.py", line 18
>       print ("%s"%(line), file=file_out)
>                               ^

Code:

```
import fnmatch
import os

rootPath = '/xxx/xxx//'
pattern = 'xxx.txt'

file_in = open(os.path.join(root, filename),"r")
file_out = open("output.txt", "w")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
    print( os.path.join(root, filename))
    for line in file_in:
            print ("%s"%(line), file=file_out)
    file_in.close()
    file_out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you're probably running Python 2, where the `file` keyword hadn't been introduced.

Change the `print ("%s"%(line), file=file_out)` line by `file_out.write(line+"\n")`, which is equivalent, simpler, and works in all python versions so far.

But since the file iterator issues lines with end-of-line included, you don't want 2 newlines so just write `file_out.write(line)`

Comment: Don't forget to add the newline yourself if you're going to use the `file.write` method.

Comment: you're right, but I think the OP doesn't want 2 newlines (`line` already has a newline because file iterator issues it)